# Знаки препинания в перечислении

Tags: пунктуация, перечисление, точка-с-запятой

Проверяю приказ и не понимаю, почему в первом пункте идёт перечисление и в конце перечисления стоит точка с запятой, когда следующим идёт п. 2?

Comment: Почему стоит тчк/зпт, а не зпт или тчк?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в вашем вопросе речь идет об оформлении перечня (если имеется в виду **точка с запятой** в конце перечисления в первом пункте). В этом случае оформление должно быть таким:
**1)** текст 1, ещё текст с перечислением;
**2)** текст 2;
**3)** текст 3, текст 4.

Или таким:
**1.** Текст 1, ещё текст с перечислением.
**2.** Текст 2.
**3.** Текст 3, текст 4.

После абзацев — элементов перечня ставится:
б) **точка с запятой**, если элементы не совсем просты, со знаками препинания внутри, обозначены цифрой с закрывающей скобкой, строчной буквой с закрывающей скобкой, наборным знаком и начинаются со строчной буквы, т. е. строчной букве в начале элемента соответствует точка с запятой в конце его.

Вот пример из [правил Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=14#pp14).

> **2.** После двоеточия первое слово пишется с прописной буквы:
> **1)** если это начало прямой речи: *Маленькая девочка бежала и кричала: «Не видали маму?»* (М. Г.)**;**
> **2)** если это начало цитаты, являющейся самостоятельным предложением: *В критической статье «Мильон терзаний» И. А. Гончаров писал: «Сам Грибоедов приписал горе Чацкого его уму, а Пушкин отказал ему вовсе в уме»*.

[Как оформлять перечни?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/83-rubric-77)